# Can someone explain what function($) does in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Recently I was reading someone else's code, and came across this:

```
// Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
// Encapsulation
// $ is assigned to jQuery
;(function($) {

     // DOM Ready
    $(function() {
        ...
  });

})(jQuery);
```

I understand the point of the leading ;, And I understand that $(function() { is the same as document ready, but what is the point of adding function($)?

I understand it's a closure, but since this is always being called at the global scope, it seems like you don't need to bother with it.  The $(function() { will use the same global object either way, no?

Is it to safeguard against something, or is it a best practice for another reason?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a common structure for a jQuery plugin. It safeguards against the `$` identifier having been overwritten and used for something else. Inside the anonymous function, `$` is always going to refer to jQuery.

Example:

```
$ = "oh no";
$(function() { //Big problem!
    //DOM ready
});
```

By introducing a new scope, you can ensure that `$` refers to what you expect it to:

```
$ = "oh no";
(function($) { //New scope, $ is redeclared and jQuery is assigned to it

    $(function() { //No problem!
        //DOM ready
    }); 

}(jQuery));
```

The main reasoning behind this is that numerous other JavaScript libraries use `$` as an identifier (e.g. PrototypeJS). If you wanted to use both Prototype and jQuery, you need to let Prototype have its `$` identifier, but you probably don't want to write out `jQuery` every time you want to call a jQuery method. By introducing a new scope you allow jQuery to have its `$` back in that execution context.

Answer (score 1):

The code sample you've provided is an example of a Self-Invoking Function:

```
(function(){
 // some code…
})();
```

The first set of parentheses defines a function: (an anonymous function wrapped in parentheses)

```
(function() {})
```

That defines the anonymous function. On its own, it doesn't do anything. But if you add a set of parentheses `()` after the definition, it's the same as the parentheses used to call a function.
Try this out:

```
(function(message) {
  alert(message);
})("Hello World");
```

That creates a function which accepts a parameter, and displays an alert box containing the provided value. Then, it immediately calls that function with a parameter of "Hello World".

---

In your example, a self-invoking function is defined. It accepts a parameter, which is named `$`. Then, the function is immediately called, with a reference to `jQuery` being passed in as the argument.

This is common if you want jQuery to operate in `noConflict()` mode (which removes the global reference to `$`).

In `noConflict()` mode, you can still access jQuery via the `jQuery` global variable, but most people would rather use `$`, so this self-calling function accepts the global `jQuery` variable as a parameter named `$` in the scope of the function, which leaves you free to use the `$` shortcut within the self-invoking function while having jQuery operate in noConflict() mode to avoid clashes with other libraries that use `$` in the global scope.

Hope this answers your question!